# How to enable mod_rewrite detailed logging

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, loglevel

I'm trying to enable mod_rewrite detailed logging at the trace3 log level, [as described in `man`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

I've put this line in my `conf`:

```
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3
```

However I'm getting this error:

> Syntax error on line 6 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/"my_site":
>   LogLevel takes one argument, Level of verbosity in error logging

My Apache version is: Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu)

This is excerption from my conf file:

```
<VirtualHost 10.10.10.14:80>
    ServerName my_site <br>
    DocumentRoot "/data/website/php./web" <br>
    ErrorLog "/data/website/logs/error.log <br>
    CustomLog "/data/website/logs/access.log combined <br>
    LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3 <br>
</VirtualHost>
```

Please, help me to correct LogLevel statement.
Thanks.

Comment: Were the '<br>' tags in the actual file? That would have been the problem!

Answer (score 7):

You're looking at the wrong documentation!

> RewriteLog
>
> Those familiar with earlier versions of mod_rewrite will no doubt be looking for the RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel directives. This functionality has been completely replaced by the new per-module logging configuration mentioned above

You need to look at the [Apache 2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) documentation and use the [RewriteLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) and [RewriteLogLevel](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteloglevel) directives.

Comment: The documentation says to use httpd.conf. Ubuntu does not have this file.

Comment: Sucks to use ubuntu.